# How do I open images in Preview at full size?

Tags: macos, preview

Is there a way I can get Preview to open images in Actual Size by default and not have it fit to screen? I vaguely remember this as an option in previous versions of Preview, but am unable to find anything in the current version. System is 10.7.3 with Preview Version 5.5.1 (719.11).

Comment: I think the most bothersome issue is when you Command + 0 (zero) and turn to the next page, it reverts to Fit to Screen and then you have to change it again; very annoying for reading many pages.

Answer (score 1):

View>Actual Size or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>0 (zero)</kbd>:

[image: View>Actual Size]

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do that. I am asking about having it default to opening at full size. Not opening, then changing size.